# How to link a VPS to a domain name

Tags: dns, vps

I am a complete newbie to this. I recently completed a course in Java Programming working towards the OCJA Exam. I had never programmed before and I don't have much web experience besides as a user. I got a work placement and I am in way over my head.

I have to connect a VPS to the domain of the site we're working on and I don't know how to do it. I think I use a control panel but I'm working on a Mac and cPanel doesn't work on it, I can't seem to find a working alternative either. It's a java applet if that makes any difference?

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Who is hosting your domain ? In that just point the A record to the VPS IP and wait ~24 hours for it to work.